# Should I enforce out-parameters being non-NULL?

Tags: com

Example method in IDL:

```
HRESULT _stdcall a_method( [in] long value, [out] BSTR *comment );
```

My function logic is that for some values, no comment is necessary. Should I throw an exception if this function is called with `comment == NULL` by a client? Or is it OK to be permissive and allow this case?

(I'm developing my object in C++).

My rationale for trying to be strict with parameter checking is that I'm concerned about memory leaks, and about having the client make calls that are correct according to the COM spec but my object not accepting the call.

Comment: Are you expecting to use `a_method` as an RPC?

Comment: do you mean, am I expecting to use it in an out-of-process server?  Currently my server is in-process although I may develop an oop version in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semantics of `[out]` parameters are very explicit about this.

A method that gets an `[out]` parameter should never - ever - look at the parameter's value until it puts something on it. It is uninitialized memory. Garbage. In fact, if your method is called via a marshalled call (inter-apartment or inter-process), garbage is exactly what you get: whatever your caller might have put there when it called your method, was discarded and ignored by the proxy/stub; you never get it.

If the client/caller puts something on the parameter before making a call to your method, it is definitely a memory leak (given that it's an allocated object like a BSTR, of course), but it's the caller's fault. It is never the responsibility of a called method to deal with it. The called method can't handle the leak even if it wanted to.

If you want to handle whatever values might be passed in by the caller, you need to use an `[in, out]` parameter instead of `[out]`.

One last warning: **Automation** clients (VBA, VBScript, etc.) don't support `[out]` parameters. Automation will silently handle any `[out]` parameter as if it was `[in, out]`, which puts you in an awkward position: any value placed in the parameter by the client application *will* be leaked, and your method can't do anything about it.

If you plan on your object being used by an automation client, don't use `[out]` parameters. Use `[in, out]` instead, and make sure to check if the caller put a value on the parameter before the call. The proxy/stub will always marshal values both ways for an `[in, out]` parameter. If the caller placed a value on the parameter before the call, your method is responsible for releasing that value before writing to the parameter.

**Edit: Expanding on the pointer itself being NULL:**

You could think about checking for NULL and return `E_INVALIDARG` if it's NULL, but I wouldn't recommend it.

It is illegal to pass NULL as the pointer value for an `[out]` parameter. Even if your code handles a NULL value, if the call is marshalled, the marshaller will hit an Access Violation. The marshaller has to access the pointed value on the way back (to store the marshalled output on it) and it will do so without checking for null.

In your specific scenario (the call semantic being that there is nothing to return in a given case), the proper process is for the caller to always provide a pointer to storage, and for the called method to set the value to NULL. Something like this:

```
// Caller
BSTR comment;
hr = obj->a_method( 42, &comment);

// Callee
HRESULT a_method( value, BSTR *comment )
{
    if (...)
    {
        //... I've decided we don't need to return a comment
        *comment = NULL;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you really want to have the pure null pointer semantic you mentioned, you can; but you have to mark the parameter with the `[ptr]` attribute. As far as I know, that doesn't work very well with Automation clients, and you have to use a custom marshaller. If you don't anticipate ever using an Automation client, this is clearly an option.

Comment: By "Automation clients don't support `[out]`", I presume you are excluding `[out, retval]` -- which Automation does support?

Comment: @MattMcNabb, oh, I see; I misunderstood the core of your question. I've edited with more details on what to do with the pointer. @Jeffamaphone, yes, `[ptr]` would work.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, correct. `[out, retval]` is handled correctly by Automation.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer and just what I needed to know :)  Is there a specification document anywhere that says things like "it is illegal for the client to pass NULL as the pointer value"? I have tried reading MS's COM specification (from 1995) but it is rather informal , and doesn't cover this.

Comment: I'm sure there is a formal reference. Somewhere. I'll try to hunt something down. I didn't know COM in 1995, but I suspect a lot of these rules were still being sorted-out at the time. Many are corollaries of working out the details: "what's the only sensible rule?". And I believe that a lot of the rules are actually inherited from RPC.

Comment: *"You could think about checking for NULL and return E_INVALIDARG if it's NULL, but I wouldn't recommend it."*  I beg to differ, I recommend you check for `NULL` `[out]` arguments and return `E_POINTER` when you find one.  This will allow you to catch/detect errors early.